# Exponential function with bash, awk or similar

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, bc

I have this text file:

```
$ cat resultados.txt 
10.8
12.1
14.2
14.8
19.4
8.62
9.73
```

**Important**: numbers are in rows, not in columns.

I want to perform the geometrical operation:

```
e((l(number1)+l(number2)+l(numbern))/n)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another alternative for geometric mean

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p=1} {p*=$0; n++} END{print p^(1/n)}' file
12.3846
```

or, with NR

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{p=1} {p*=$0} END{print p^(1/NR)}' file
```

Comment: For large number of elements, you may want to use exp(sum log / n) solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question would be clearer if you provided the expected output given that input but is this what you're looking for?

```
$ awk '{sum+=log($0)} END{if (NR) print sum, sum/NR, exp(sum/NR)}' file
17.6152 2.51646 12.3846
```